# Mssql / nodejs ConnectionPool is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

Im currently following a tutorial on Youtube about nodejs and mssq.
While following the tutorial, i came across an issue about ConnectionPool.
Since it's a 5 years old video, the nodejs plugin changed overtime (mssq/tedious).

My version is now 6.2.0 for mssql/tedious (latest version)

It's not using "sql.Connection(config)" anymore.
Many people reported that changing sql.Connection(config) to sql.ConnectionPool(config)fixed their issues.

but for me, it did not.

Below you'll find 3 files but the line that makes it go bad is this one (connect.js):

```js
var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
```

the config is actually this :

```js
exports.config = {
  user: 'dataGetter',
  password: '1234',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'cegeptest',
};
```

Errors:

```
TypeError: sql.ConnectionPool is not a constructor
    at Object.exports.connectDatabase (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\database\connect.js:7:14)
    at Object.exports.getList (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\database\queries\villes.js:5:11)
    at C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\routes\villes.routes.js:6:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\_Programming\Work\InventoryCegep\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

**Thanks in advance for the help :)**

Here's the code related to this:

**villes.routes.js**

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const villes = require('../database/queries/villes.js');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //database.getList(req, res);
  villes.getList(req, res);
  res.render('villes');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**villes.js**

```js
var connect = require('../connect');
//CRUD pour villes

exports.getList = function (req, res) {
  connect.connectDatabase('SELECT * FROM Ville', function (data, err) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHeader(500, 'Internal error occured', {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      });
      res.write(
        '<html><head><title>500</title></head><body>500: internal error. Details: ' +
          err +
          '</body></html>'
      );
    } else {
      res.writeHeader(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
      res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    res.end();
  });
}; //sortir la liste complète des villes
```

**connect.js**

```js
var sql = require('mssql'); //On call le module microsoft Sql   (Installer avec :  npm i mssql)
var config = require('../settings').config; //On va chercher notre configuration exportée dans database/config.js

//sql.connect(config).then((pool) => {});

exports.connectDatabase = function (sql, callback) {
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  console.log(conn);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
var sql = require('mssql'); //On call le module microsoft Sql   (Installer avec :  npm i mssql)
var config = require('../settings').config; //On va chercher notre configuration exportée dans database/config.js

//sql.connect(config).then((pool) => {});

exports.connectDatabase = function (sql, callback) {
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  console.log(conn);

};
```

The function parameter `sql` is overriding the actual `sql` module. Rename it to `sqlText` and it will work.

```
exports.connectDatabase = function (sqlText, callback) {
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  console.log(conn);

};
```

Comment: @Dave if this solved your problem plz keep a habit of marking the best answer